# How to iterate controls in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, controls, iterator

I have a simple XAML file with a grid in it and textboxes. But when using my code it does not find the textboxes by iteration.

VB.Net:

```
Dim ctl As FrameworkElement = Me.MainWindow
```

Code:

```
Dim ChildrenCount As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ctl)
'ChildrenCount is always zero
For i As Integer = 0 To ChildrenCount - 1
    Dim Child As FrameworkElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ctl, i)
    Call SetLanguageToControls(Keyword, cLanguage, Child)
Next
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"  Icon="/OUTPUT%20-%20Histogram;component/Sprectrum.ico">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid x:Name="SpectrumContent" Margin="8" Height="120" Width="320">
            <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Opacity="0.5">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="White" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtRedMin" Text="|Red:" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtRedMinValue" Text="000%" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**EDIT**
Problem is solved. I used the code while managing language in my plugins. But MainWindow1.Loaded was not called. If Window is not loaded, this code does not work. If Window is loaded, this code works.

Comment: What code defines `ctl`?

Comment: Base is the main window. I want to receive a list of all controls by iteration. The question is not how to iterate, the question is how to receive the list of children of frameworkelement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your function recursively for each child control. That is, in the following line you get a child of `ctl`:

```
Dim Child As FrameworkElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ctl, i)
```

After this, you need to iterate over children of `Child`.

Comment: But 'i' is always -1 because Count is zero

Comment: @goldengel When are you calling this? Maybe it's before the UI for the window has been created?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what control you pass as `ctl`

If you pass the Window you'll get the Border

If you pass the Grid (Layout) you'll get the child grid.

**EDIT**

I just noticed this line

```
Dim ctl As FrameworkElement = Me.MainWindow
```

Change it into:

```
Dim ctl As FrameworkElement = Me
```

**EDIT2**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ctl As FrameworkElement
    ctl = LayoutRoot
    Dim ChildrenCount As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ctl)
    For i As Integer = 0 To ChildrenCount - 1
        Dim Child As FrameworkElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(ctl, i)
        Debug.WriteLine(Child.ToString() + ": " +
                        VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(Child).ToString())
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps I can filter by doing "If typeof ctl is Window Then". But later, how to catch children?

Comment: Do not filter. Pass the parent of the children you are looking for to the function and use a recursive method to find the children of the children.

Comment: Also: I found something that is wrong as well. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Erno for your reply. If I send my MainWindow as Frameworkelement to the class above, I receive the MainWindow but 'VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ctl)' returns zero. If cast the MainWindow and use the 'ctl = MainWindow.Content' then ctl is a Grid but with 'VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(ctl)' zero and .Children zero (that is unusual). I don't understand why it is 0.

Comment: Solved! I've asked for controls BEFORE MainWindow1.Loaded was called. Thanks for great help

Comment: Indeed, the visual tree is not loaded. Only after Window.Loaded has been raised the tree is available.

Answer (score 1):

The `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` method does not recurse. If you want recursion try using [Linq-To-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), e.g.

```
var textBlocks = ctl.Descendants<TextBlock>();
```

Comment: I know it is not recursively. But Descendants is not available on my type of ctl which is Frameworkelement. Can you advice me?

Comment: Try following the link in the answer: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/ !!

Comment: Greate aricle of how to use LINQ. But the solution was not by filtering stuff but by using code before UI was created. Thanks Colin for your help.